# Call Javascript Function with argument and use argument as a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following snip of a code:

```
var about = "about.html";

function loadPage(target){
    $("#dashboard").load(target);
}

$(".nav li").click(function(){
    loadPage($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

So when I click on a button like `<li class="about">`, `target` is = *about*.
But in that way, `$("#dashboard").load(target);` doesn't load the variable about which is the html-file which I want to load.

So how is it possible to call the variable in this way?

Comment: You need a page name extension perhaps? And this will fail with a multiple class similar to `class="myclass about myotherclass"`

Comment: I think clarification of you question as "I want to use the class attribute to indicate which variable I want to reference" might be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to miss the `.html` part. Try with

```
$("#dashboard").load(target+'.html');
```

But, supposing you have only one class on your `li` element, you'd better use `this.className` rather than `$(this).attr("class")`.

EDIT :

if you want to use your `about` variable, you may do this :

```
$("#dashboard").load(window[target]);
```

But it would thus be cleaner to have a map :

```
var pages = {
   'about': 'about.html',
   'home': 'welcome.jsp'
}
function loadPage(target){
    $("#dashboard").load(pages[target]);
}
$(".nav li").click(function(){
    loadPage(this.className);
});
```

Comment: Okay, this is a good alternate. But is it not possible to call a variable like that? In case it's not a html page, something else and i MUST call this variable. How is that possible?

Comment: @user2413035 I'm not sure I understand you. Do the edit answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

A stupid answer : create a `<a>` tag, and set its `href` attribute to the correct value.

Otherwise :

A standard way to store `key: values` pairs in javascript is to use a plain object :

```
var urls = {};
urls['about'] = 'mysuperduperurlforabout.html';

function loadPage(target) {
    var url = urls[target];
    //maybe check if url is defined ?

    $('#dashboard').load(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav li").click(function(){
    loadPage($(this).attr("class") + ".html");
});
```

or

```
$("#dashboard").load(target+".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the variables like this (if that's what you asked):

```
var test = 'we are here';
var x = 'test';
console.log(window[x]);
```

It's similar to the $$ in PHP. The output will be:

`we are here` in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the "about" as an object or array reference similar to:

```
var pageReferences = [];
pageReferences["about"] = "about.html";

var otherReference = {
    "about": "about.html"
};

function loadPage(target) {
    alert(pageReferences[target]);
    alert(otherReference[target]);
    $("#dashboard").load(target);
}

$(".nav li").click(function () {
    loadPage($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Both of these alerts will alert "about.html" referencing the appropriate objects.

EDIT: IF you wished to populate the object based on markup you could do:

```
var otherReference = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav').find('li').each(function () {
        var me = $(this).attr('class');
        otherReference[me] = me + ".html";
    });
});
```

You could even store the extension in an additional attribute:

```
var otherReference = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav').find('li').each(function () {
        var me = $(this).attr('class');
        otherReference[me] = me + "." + $(this).attr("extension");
    });
});
```

Better would be to simply put the page reference in a data element:

```
<li class="myli" data-pagetoload="about.html">Howdy</li>

$(".nav li").click(function () {
    loadPage($(this).data("pagetoload"));
});
```

Comment: Don't use an array if you're not using numeric keys. `var pageReferences = {};` would be the appropriate thing for this purpose.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, an array this way is not the best, but it is possible :)